# Get the full text of a textbox in a keypress event

Tags: vb.net, keypress

This is my code:

```
Private Sub prices_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles wholeprice_input_new_item.KeyPress, dozenprice_input_new_item.KeyPress, detailprice_input_new_item.KeyPress, costprice_input_new_item.KeyPress

        Dim TxtB As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
        Dim rex As Regex = New Regex("^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}$")

        'MsgBox(TxtB.Text())    

        If (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar.ToString() = "." Or e.KeyChar = CChar(ChrW(Keys.Back))) Then
            If (TxtB.Text.Trim() <> "") Then
                If (rex.IsMatch(TxtB.Text) = False And e.KeyChar <> CChar(ChrW(Keys.Back))) Then
                    e.Handled = True
                End If
            End If
        Else
            e.Handled = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

The textbox's Text property doesn't include the last character pressed, example:

```
 Text entered = "12.1"
 TxtB.Text = "12."

 Text entered = "11.."
 TxtB.Text = "11."

 Text entered = "12"
 TxtB.Text = "1"
```

I want to validate all the characters.  How I can make the event keypress validate all characters in a text box?

Comment: Your question doesn't make it clear what is wrong or what you need the code to do.  If it is currently doing something wrong, please specify the problem.  If you could give an example of what you need it to do, that would be helpful.

Comment: I agree w/ SteveDog that something doesn't add up here.  Your code removes the last character typed if it would make the TextBox string invalid, that's clear enough.  But can you clarify your examples?  Are you saying that if you enter "12.1" then the code removes the last keypress and makes it "12."?  (That would be a mystery to me, because "12.1" is clearly valid for the given Regex pattern.)  Or what do you mean by the examples?

Comment: It is correct to the examples demonstrate that with the keypress event when the textbox has "12.12" validates the event nothing more. "12.1" I need the event to validate everything that contains the textbox without deleting any character

Comment: No character is deleted in your code, please add some examples of inputs, and whether or not it should be valid.

Comment: Please see my last edit, and add a msgbox

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear to future visitors. I also removed REGEX from the title because the problem is not about Regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the KeyPress event, the key that's being pressed is not yet added to the textbox. You could add the character that's being pressed to the existing text, something like this:

```
Dim TxtB As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
If (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) OrElse e.KeyChar = "."c Then
    Dim fullText As String = TxtB.Text & e.KeyChar
    'Do validation with fullText
End If
```

Comment: This was just what I needed, I appreciate your help + REP

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's a little more complicated than that - what if the user pressed the backspace key, for instance? You might be better advised to use the TextChanged event instead, which fires after the Text property has been updated by the last key pressed.